# Rust Axum router Sub directories

Tags: rust, router, rust-tokio, rust-axum

I'm just starting to learn Rust Axum and I'm wondering how I should structure my project.

Right now, my project is a simple in memory to-do app stolen from a YouTube tutorial, where he defines a router for the specific folder.
Structure right now looks like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
   ├── in_memory
   │  ├── mod.rs
   │  ├── routes.rs
   │  └── state.rs
   └── main.rs
```

I do not feel comfortable with the functions being used for routes all written in the same file, but I'm ok whit it being like that.

If someone knows if I can write a file where then I could import the functionality awesome.

Now my problem is the following:

If I want to make my project bigger and add another section, where should I put all the new code?
Am I obliged to use the same file?

Comment: Your project layout is strange, are `Cargo.*` really on the same level as `main.rs`? Also I don't see a problem with splitting `routes.rs` up into multiple modules, where did you hit a roadblock?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. No, they're not. They are one level above. Also, thanks for the information about writing many `routes.rs`. I was asking which the best practice is to order my project in different subfolders (ex: If I move the in_memory folder inside a `components` folder) and how to import everything into the `main.rs` file.

Comment: You should really read the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), and specifically the section on [separating modules into different files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know if you can split your routes into separate files. If so you can try this.

First create modules. Export your routes for those modules in them
and use merge to merge these routes in your main file

- routes

  - route1.rs
  - route2.rs
- routes.rs
- main.rs

route1.rs

```
pub async fn list(
  request: Request,
) -> Json<serde_json::Value> {
  let val= SOMETHING
  Json(val)
}

pub fn_get_routes(){
  Router::new()
  .route("/",get(list))
  ... other routes
}
```

routes.rs

```
mod route1;
mod route2;
```

main.rs

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

let app = Router::new()       
    .merge(routes::route1::get_routes())
    .merge(routes::route2::get_routes())

run(app).await
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {

  let app = Router::new()     
    .merge(routes::route1::get_routes())
    
  run(app).await
}
```

[Merge Routes](https://docs.rs/crate/axum/latest/source/src/docs/routing/merge.md#:%7E:text=This%20is%20useful%20for%20breaking%20apps%20into%20smaller,%5B%60Router%60%5D%20must%20have%20the%20same%20type%20of%20state.) ,
[Separate Modules into different files](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch07-05-separating-modules-into-different-files.html)